# Windows Service unable to detect EDMX context

Tags: entity-framework, windows-services

I have a 3 layer application layer and i am using the EF framework. Now the EDMX file resides on the DAL layer.

I have a windows service that will be activated at 10:00 PM every night. This service activates a method on the BLL which in turn uses the Context for doing stuff.

But when my **service activates and calls the method in the BLL** it throws an error:

**The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid.**

I don't exactly know how to get around with this.

Comment: Why not read what the exception is telling you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app.config file in windows service does not contain necessary connectionString or it's name might have changed and it may not match.